# I'm a beginner in discord botting and I'm using discord.js in node.js in visual studio. I can't figure out how to solve this error

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a discord bot that does this

If there's *interesting in the message it splits it from the message and sends everything else combined with the string " I'm not dad. I'm bad discord bot"

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot2 = new Discord.Client();

const token2 = 'Not showing my token';
const mark = '*';
bot2.on('message', msg =>{
   let args = msg.content.substring(mark.length).split(" ")
   if(args[0] === "interesting"){
      let argus = args.content.substring("interesting".length).split(" ")
      var thee = concat(argus, " I'm not dad. I'm bad discord bot")
      msg.channel.send(thee)
   }


})




bot2.login(token2)
```

I changed the token thing so It doesn't show here. Here's the error I get when I ran this.
c:\Users\Artashes\Desktop\bots\letus\index.js:9
      let argus = args.content.substring("interesting".length).split(" ")
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

I eventually understood that the thing that was not defined was args.content.

I tried changing it to args with no avail.

I also tried doing args.prototype but the same error appeared.

How can I fix this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```js
let argus = args.content.substring("interesting".length).split(" ")
```

You are using `args` instead of `msg`. Since `args` is an array, the field `.content` returns `undefined`. If you are looking to substring the message sent by the user, do `msg.content.substring(.....`

While I am here, I should also add

1. `concat` is not a method that can be called out of nowhere. You need to use it like this: `array.concat(stringOrArray)`
2. You need to provide a string to `msg.channel.send(...)` which you can achieve using `.join(" ")` on an array of strings.

> I highly recommend you take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

**Translated into your code**

```
let argus = args.content.substring("interesting".length).split(" ")
// Changed to
let argus = msg.content.substring("interesting".length).split(" ");
```

```
var thee = concat(argus, " I'm not dad. I'm bad discord bot")
// Changed to
var thee = argus.concat(" I'm not dad. I'm bad discord bot").join(" ");
```